# InvalidSelectorException Error while trying to get text from div class in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get text using Selenium WebDriver and here is my code. Please note that I don't want to use XPath, because in my case the ID gets changed on every relaunch of the web page.

My code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("05uR6d").text
```

HTML:

```
<div class="O5uR6d">to fasten stuff</div>
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

Error is specific to the line of code I mentioned above.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to get it's xpath instead.

Comment: I don't want to use XPath, because in my case the ID gets changed on every relaunch of the web page.

Comment: Add html code where this selector is.

Comment: @AkshayRF it doesn't matter if the id gets changed or not if the class name remains same then you can apply xpath on the class as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `xpath`:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'to fasten stuff')]")
```

Or this `CSS`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".O5uR6d")
```

If both won't work, improve your question by adding more data of HTML you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using multiple ways let me try to explain most of them.

1. Get element by class name.

this is the most easiest solution to get any element by class name you can simply do is:

`driver.find_element_by_class_selector('foo');`

2. Get Element by xpath

This is a bit tricky one, you can apply xpath either the class name, title, id or whatever remains same. it also works even if there's a text inside your div. For example:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tagname[@attribute='value']")`

or in your case:

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div['class='O5uR6d']")`

or you can do something like @vitaliis said

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'to fasten stuff')]")`

You can read more about xpath and how to find it on this [link](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

3. Get Elements by ID:

You can also get the element from id if there's any that's static:
`driver.find_element_by_id('baz')`

4. Get Elements by Name:

Get Elements by name using the following syntax:
`driver.find_element_by_name('bazz')`

5. Using CSS Selectors:

You can also use the css selectors to find the elements. Consider a following tag that has some attributes:
`<p class="content">Site content goes here.</p>`

You can get this element by:
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.content')`

You can read more about it over [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Instance of 'WebDriver' has no 'find_element_by_class_selector' member

Comment: You can read more about it over here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html